# ILMerge strange behaviour

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, ilmerge

I have an issue using the latest version of ILMerge and I would like if someone can explain me if this is normal. During my search on the web I realized I was not using the latest version of ILMerge so I updated my projects and this is where everything got wrong… First let me explain quickly my project dependencies:

- The dll project A references and uses ILMerge.
- The dll project B references and uses the dll A but it do not reference ILMerge.
- The application project C reference the dll B but it do not reference A
  nor ILMerge.

My issue is : with the latest version of ILMerge the file is not copied in the output bin folder when the projects B or C are compiled.

*With the ILMerge version 2.11.502.0:*

- When I build the dll project A the bin folder contains A.dll and
  ILMerge.exe.
- When I build the dll project B the bin folder contains
  B.dll, A.dll and ILMerge.exe.
- When I build the dll project C the bin
  folder contains C.dll, B.dll, A.dll and ILMerge.exe.

*However, with the ILMerge version 2.14.1208:*

- When I build the dll project A the bin folder contains A.dll and
  ILMerge.exe.
- When I build the dll project B the bin folder contains
  B.dll and A.dll.
- When I build the dll project C the bin folder
  contains C.dll, B.dll and A.dll.

When I made the move to use the latest version of ILMerge I updated the reference in my project A and make sure to set the property Copy Local to true.  When I revert back to the older version it works as expected and the file is copied everywhere.

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have been told by Mike Barnett from Microsoft that this weird behavior exists also with VS2013 but not with VS2015.

Did someone ever encounter a similar issue?

Here is an example: [ILMergeIssue.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B27PiQRBFSJTaGNQQ0JqWk9HX2c)

Comment: Strange question.  There is no conceivable point in referencing ILMerge.exe at all, that I can think of anyway.  The point of the utility is to have *less* executable files.  Just run it in a post-build event, no reference needed.

Comment: Well I am using ILMerge.exe as a dll, if I may say, since I am referencing it and using its API directly from my code instead of doing it in a command prompt.

Comment: Your NotWorkingILMergeNet4 solution works just fine when I build it on VS2015 Update 2.  You need to look at the detailed build trace, focus on the ResolveAssemblyReference and CopyFilesToOutputDirectory tasks.  I see it find and copy ilmerge.exe for all three projects.

Comment: As I mentioned, Mike Barnett said the same thing: it works with VS2015. However the issue is with VS2012 and VS2013. There is no error with those version. I am not aware of any special verbose mode during compilation to see how/when VS is copying dependency files.

Comment: Mike's semantic versioning scheme trips a bug in older versions of MSBuild.  His assembly version is 2.14.1208.65535, MSBuild doesn't like 65535, looks for a match with 2.14.1208 instead and won't find it .  He should have picked 0, like he did for version 2.11.502.0.  I can't otherwise tell why he liked 65535 better.

Comment: Windows Explorer tells me the version is 2.14.1208.0 but Telerik JustDecompile says the AssemblyVersion is 2.14.1208.65535... So you think that if he changes the last version digit from 65535 to 0 it should work?

Comment: Windows Explorer can only show the [AssemblyFileVersion].  The [AssemblyVersion] is the problem.  Yes.

Comment: Thanks I will discuss about this with Mike Barnett. I really appreciate your time Hans!

Comment: @DavidH What did you find out from Mike Barnett?