# Reserved max value in the .NET assembly version

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I wonder why the assembly version can not have the max `UInt16` values. The [MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version(v=vs.110).aspx) that:

> All components of the version must be integers greater than or equal
>   to zero. Metadata restricts the major, minor, build, and revision
>   components for an assembly to a maximum value of UInt16.MaxValue - 1.

Does anyone know what the max value is reserved for?

**UPDATE 1**

It's not a duplicate question. I'm not asking about the max value of `UInt16` itself, that is 6553**5**. I'm asking why the **max possible value for version** is 6553**4**. I haven't found any explanation about internal usage of the last value and why it is reserved in .NET.

**UPDATE 2**

People say that max value could be used for `*`. Yes, it is really possible to set the assembly version to something like **1.0.***. And I did it. And then checked the manifest of the compiled file:

[image]

And as you can see, compiler didn't set build and revision to **65535**. Instead, it has generated some specific values. So, probably max value is not for `*`.

Comment: That's not a duplicate but the accepted answer explains it (probably for the `*`)

Comment: I *think* they tried to put 65535 in their back-pocket, reserving it to mean "not specified".  This was used in the ILMerge.exe utility, and [promptly blew up badly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38443002/17034).  So stay away from it, dragons live there.

Comment: See Also: The OP's blog contains a [helpful list of restrictions on version numbers](https://binary-studio.com/2017/08/18/software-versioning-windows-net/).

Answer (score 4):

[**Why are build numbers limited to 65534?**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa381058.aspx)

*FILEVERSION*

> Binary version number for the file. The version consists of two 32-bit integers, defined by four 16-bit integers. For example, "FILEVERSION 3,10,0,61" is translated into two doublewords: 0x0003000a and 0x0000003d, in that order. Therefore, if version is defined by the DWORD values dw1 and dw2, they need to appear in the FILEVERSION statement as follows: HIWORD(dw1), LOWORD(dw1), HIWORD(dw2), LOWORD(dw2).

Metadata restricts major, minor, build, and revision to a maximum of UInt16.MaxValue - 1. [ref](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System/types/Version.html)

Comment: That does not explain why you can't use *65535*, which is what the question is about. `FILEVERSION` has no mention of such a restriction, it simply explains how the numbers are stored. We already know the managed metadata has the restriction, the question was about *why*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ill clarify what is affected as soon as Im on a computer. And Ive only found references explaining that the last bit is used for metadata. I ve found no mention about what metadata.

Comment: The reference only explains what I've wrote in the question. Nothing says about how .NET or OS uses the max value.